# How to start a List<Task> in parallel?

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library

I have an object that returns a `System.Threading.Tasks.Task`:

```
public class MyClass 
{
    public Task GetTask(object state, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        return new Task(Execute, state, cancellationToken);
    }

    public void Execute(object context)
    {
        //do stuff
    }
}
```

Elsewhere I have a `List<MyClass>`, so I do the following to get a `List<Task>`:

```
var myTaskList = myClassList.Select(p => p.GetTask(null, cancellationToken)).ToList();
```

Now that I have the `List<Task>`, how can I start them all in parallel? Is there a more concise way to code this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 29, accepted):

What do you mean by "start them in parallel"? When you run the `Task`, it executes on another thread, so you probably mean simply:

```
foreach(var task in myTaskList)
{
    task.Start();
}
```

But if you have so many of them that you want to move the starting logic to another thread, you can either call the above code in another thread/task (I'm using `List<T>.ForEach` for shorter code).

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() => myTaskList.ForEach(task => task.Start()));
```

Or you can use TPL's `Parallel.ForEach`. That would still block the executing thread until all the Tasks are started, but it will execute the start action on an internal threadpool, so for large numbers of items and some free CPU cores/threads, it might speed up the starting considerably.

```
Parallel.ForEach(myTaskList, task => task.Start());
```

Comment: Thank you, the `Parallel.ForEach()` was what I was looking for.

Comment: `Parallel.ForEach` will still block the current thread until it has completed all of its iterations.

Comment: You are right - the question was quite unclear, but so is my answer. Truly parallel way is to execute (any) `task.Start()` logic in a separate thread (i.e. Thread object, Task with LongRunning creation option, Parallel.Invoke etc.)

Comment: A nitpick on an otherwise great answer. There's no such thing as "LINQ's ForEach" in the middle example. The `ForEach` you're using is a method on `List<T>` and `Enumerable` does not provide a `ForEach` method. (For good reason: for each does not return a value to which you could chain further computation and so in most cases you could just `foreach`.)

Comment: True, it's defined for `List<T>` only and uses a `for` internally, but I noticed it together with LINQ, so I tend to call it that way. I'll clarify my answer.

Answer (score 7):

I might be misunderstanding your question, but isn't it just to call Start on every task?

```
foreach(Task task in myTaskList) 
{
    task.Start();
}
```

Waiting for all the tasks to finish:

```
Task.WaitAll(myTaskList.ToArray());
```

Comment: Or, via Linq: myTaskList.ForEach(task => task.Start());

Comment: I was unable to run Parallel.Foreach on my Task because it was a promise-styled Task; this Task.WaitAll worked for me instead.

Comment: @sphair "Task.WaitAll(myTaskList.ToArray());" gives me "Cannot await 'void'"