# Start List of Task in Task.WhenAll

Tags: c#, task, task-parallel-library

I have a list of Task, which I have added them in Task.WhenAll :

```
List<Task> taskList = new List<Task>();
taskList.Add(new Task(() => {  }));
taskList.Add(new Task(() => {  }));
taskList.Add(new Task(() => {  }));

Task.WhenAll(taskList)
                .ContinueWith((completedReference) =>
                {
                    taskList.ForEach(x => x.Dispose());
                });
```

Is there any way to start all the tasks from List just after adding them in Task.WhenAll?

Comment: Can you please explain what you're trying to achieve by this? There's a simple answer to this - `foreach(var task in taskList) task.Start();`. But you don't want to do that. Instead you're favouring an approach that can't be done. So what's the underlying need here?

Answer (score 0):

```
List<Task> taskList = new List<Task>();
taskList.Add(new Task(() => {  }));
taskList.Add(new Task(() => {  }));
taskList.Add(new Task(() => {  }));

foreach(var task in taskList)
{
    task.Start();
}

Task.WhenAll(taskList)
```

Or, you can create task and start it at one moment:

```
List<Task> taskList = new List<Task>();
taskList.Add(Task.Run(() => {  }));
taskList.Add(Task.Run(() => {  }));
taskList.Add(Task.Run(() => {  }));
```

Comment: Thanks for the direction. Actually, i want to start all the tasks just when Task.WhenAll is invoked, since taskList.Add(Task.Run(() => {  })); will start the task even before adding it to Task.WhenAll

Comment: @YeasinAbedinSiam why? I don't understand. `Task.WhenAll` waits tasks running to complete. You need to run tasks before.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() => taskList.ForEach(task => task.Start()));
```

or you can try

```
Parallel.ForEach(taskList, task => task.Start());
```

That would still block the executing thread until all the Tasks are started, but it will execute the start action on an internal thread pool,

for more [How to start a List<Task> in parallel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13837662/how-to-start-a-listtask-in-parallel)